# proof of relationship between $H(S)$ and $H(S^n)$

Tags: information-theory, entropy

in order to proof relationship between $H(S)$ and $H(S^n)$ in this [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHrRdiNNyo&list=PLOzRYVm0a65dhUUuWow3dmimcgOisQn4I&index=3&pp=iAQB) Professor writes an equality:

$$-\sum_{i\in S^n} p(\sigma_i)\log_2 p_{i_1} = -\sum_{i\in S^n} {p_{i_1}}{p_{i_2}}...{p_{i_n}}\log_2 p_{i_1}$$

where $p(\sigma_i) = {p_{i_1}}{p_{i_2}}...{p_{i_n}}$. and then he concluded that(in mimnute 26:00):

$$-\sum_{i=0}^{K-1} {p_{i_1}}{p_{i_2}}...{p_{i_n}}\log_2 {p_{i_1}} = $$
$$-\sum_{i_1=0}^{K-1}{p_{i_1}}\log_2 {p_{i_1}}\sum_{i_2=0}^{K-1} {p_{i_2}}  \sum_{i_3=0}^{K-1} {p_{i_3}} ... \sum_{i_n=0}^{K-1} {p_{i_n}} $$

and i can't figure out this last equality! I appreciate if anyone can provide a proof for this last equation.

Comment: The left side of your equality does not make sense (it's ok in the video), the summation should run over all the values of all the indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum in the left side of your equality should rather be $-\sum_{i\in S^n}$, that is, run over all values on all the indexes:
$$-\sum_{i\in S^n} (\cdot)= -\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2} \sum_{i_3} \cdots \sum_{i_n}  (\cdot)  $$

Now, the value inside the sum factors. Then, you are supposed to know that in such case, in general $\sum_i \sum_j (a_i \,b_j ) = \sum_i (a_i \sum_j b_j ) = ( \sum_i a_i )( \sum_j b_j) $ .